# How to compare unicode with queryset in Python

Tags: python, django, rest

`booking_date` contains 2016-05-24

`event_data.values('booking_date')` contains `[{'booking_date': datetime.date(2016, 5, 24)}]`

Here both values are the same, and when I compare these two values then it will give True. Only their type is different.

Can any one suggest how to compare these values in Python django .

```
2016-05-24 [{'booking_date': datetime.date(2016, 5, 24)}]
```

For example:

```
if event_data.values('booking_date') != booking_date:
    print booking_date,event_data.values('booking_date')
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to take the item you want to compare e.g.

```
booking = event_data.values('booking_date')[0]
```

and then do the comparition:

```
if  booking['booking_date'] != datetime.strptime(booking_date, '%Y-%m-%d'):
    ...
```